# How in graphql get last 3 element

Tags: express, sequelize.js, graphql, graphql-js

How in graphql.js get last 3 created_at element from mysql db table?
I use sequelize.js

Like this:

```
query: '{
    elements(last:3){ 
        id
    }
}'
```

This is my file db.js

```
const Conn = new Sequelize(/*connection config*/);
Conn.define('elements', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(36),
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false
    }
});
export default Conn;
```

This is my file schema.js

```
const Query = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Query',
    description: 'Root query object',
    fields() {
        return {
            elements: {
                type: new GraphQLList(Element),
                args: {
                    id: {
                        type: GraphQLString
                    }
                },
                resolve (root, args) {
                    return Db.models.elements.findAll({ where: args });
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it must be like this;

```
...
return Db.models.elements.findAll({ 
  limit: 3, 
  where: args, 
  order: [['created_at', 'DESC']] 
});
```

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#pagination-limiting
http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#ordering

Comment: Thanks for answer.
But how i can change my scheme.js?
Like this?
```lastThreeElements: {
                type: new GraphQLList(Element),
                args: {
                    id: {
                        type: GraphQLString
                    }
                },
                resolve (root, args) {
                    return Db.models.elements.findAll({
                        limit: 3,
                        where: args,
                        order: [['created_at', 'DESC']]
                    });
                }
            }```